# C# - Tab Delimited String not working if column has empty characters/spaces

Tags: c#, split, csv

I have the following text in a .txt file:

```
hello     123     example info
mello     456     xample text
yello             maple syrup
```

I am doing:

```
string FILENAME = Server.MapPath(".") + @"\example.txt";
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(FILENAME);
string[] items = allLines[i].Split('\t');
```

Now, for the last row, I am getting two consecutive empty columns instead of just skipping the second one (items[1]) and giving me the third one.

My final result looks like:

```
hello     123     example info
mello     456     xample text
yello
```

I am actually inserting the information in a database but I don't want to go into much detail because I know that the problem is in the split itself.

My final result should include the third column information in the third row.

Comment: Are you sure there are tabs between the items in the last line?

Comment: I just ran the code, and it splits the line properly into 3 components, with the second one (`items[1]`) being empty.

Comment: I also tested this and had good results like @Gjeltema. are you sure the lines you're processing have the values you think they do?

Comment: yeah it's just an example, here I add extra spacing whereas the one I will actually processes just skips it and works like I want it to. thnx.

Comment: [This overload of String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) may be handy for you.

Comment: thnx, i'll look into it. overload is actually the noun of the day for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting the line by '\t' which is correct as long as the blank space uses tabs to get there.  If they had used tabs properly, you should have ended up with exactly what you wanted.  If they had used spaces, instead, you would have ended up with all the text in your first column, just very long.  What you got instead, is nothing.  The most likely solution is that there were actually EXTRA tabs, that the output array was longer than expected, and the third column is now, for instance, in the items[3] slot instead of items[2].  It is difficult to tell you how you can control for this except that instead of checking items[2] you could test for items[items.length-1].

Comment: yeah thats it, extra tabs. thnx Ted